# Where is basic documentation for the devel module?

Tags: debugging

Can someone point me to the basic documentation about how to use the devel module to add and delete nodes, users, etc.? I did not find any links on the project page.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but the purpose of Stack Exchange is not being a repository for links. If you have a specific question, then that could be on-topic. Asking for links is off-topic for us.